# Convert string to UTF-8 escape sequence

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, cross-platform

In my C++ program I want to convert a std:string like this:

```
abc €
```

to an UTF-8 escape sequence:

```
abc%20%E2%82%AC
```

And I need it to be platform independent! All I found has been solutions only working on windows. There must be a solution out there right?

Comment: You can't have "a string like this". How is your source string encoded?

Comment: My string is like that. I guess it is Windows-1250 encoded.

Comment: @juergen d: unfortunately, guessing doesn't work. The Euro symbol has the same value in CP-1250 as in CP-1252, but other characters are different. For example, if the byte `0xA3` appears in the input string, and you interepet it as CP-1250 then it means `Ł` and should be encoded `%C5%81`. But if you interpret it as CP-1252 then it means `£` and should be encoded `%C2%A3`. If the translation is supposed to be platform independent, then by definition it can't depend on a platform-specific setting of "user's preferred Windows code page", you need to determine the encoding. Perhaps from locale.

Comment: ... but it depends where the data comes from. If you've read your `std::string` out of downloaded HTML data, then you need to detect the encoding from one of several sources: it can be in HTML `meta` elements, an XML declaration, or HTTP headers, but it's nothing to do with local user settings. If you've read it from the terminal then you need to know what charset the terminal is using, which is a local setting.

Comment: the string is a filename and I read it from the file system. And later I use it in the HTTP CONTENT-DISPOSITION filename

Comment: @juergen: At that point, you're already hosed. When you read a filename from a Windows filesystem, it should be a `std::wstring`. Windows (NTFS) filenames are UTF-16, which can be perfectly converted to UTF-8 as long as there's no intermediate non-Unicode step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to C++11, there's no mandated support for UTF-8 in the standard.

There are two steps here:

- convert to UTF-8 (unless it's already in UTF-8)
- URL-escape the result (update: James Kanze covers this part)

Neither of them is particularly difficult to write for yourself portably, assuming you know what character encoding the input string uses[*]. Which means other people have done it before, you shouldn't need to write it yourself. If you search for them separately you might have better luck finding platform-independent code for each step.

Note there are two different ways to URL-escape a space character, either as `+` or as `%20`. Your example uses `%20`, so if that's important to you then don't accidentally use a URL-escape routine that does the other.

`[*]` It's not ISO-Latin-1, since that doesn't have the Euro sign[**], but it might be Windows CP-1252.

`[**]` Unless it's been added recently. Anyway, your example codes the Euro sign as UTF-8 bytes `0xE2 0x82 0xAC`, which represent the Unicode code point `0x20AC`, not code point `0x80` which it has in CP1252. So if it was originally a single-byte encoding then clearly an intelligent single-byte-to-unicode-code-point conversion has been applied along the way. You could say there are three steps:

- convert the `std::string` to Unicode code points (depends on input encoding).
- convert the Unicode to UTF-8
- URL-escape the UTF-8

Comment: ISO-8559-15 is probably what it is, not some proprietary microencoding.

Comment: @tchrist: well, assuming that the example string has been correctly printed it's easy enough to tell the difference since the Euro is in a different place between CP-1252 and ISO-8859-15. I wouldn't like to guess the relative frequency with which the two are seen in the wild, but if you say that CP-1252 is less common than ISO-8859-15, fair enough.

Comment: One thing I do often see, though, is CP-1252 mislabelled as Latin-1. Which is annoying.

Answer (score 4):

It seems rather straightforward to me.  Your string is a sequence of
bytes.  Certain byte values (most, actually, but not the most common)
are not permitted, and should be replaced with the three character
sequence `'%'` followed by two hex characters representing the byte
value.  So something like:

```
std::string
toEscaped( std::string const& original )
{
    std::string results ;
    for ( std::string::const_iterator iter = original.begin();
            iter != original.end();
            ++ iter ) {
        static bool const allowed[] =
        {
            //  Define the 256 entries...
        };
        if ( allowed[static_cast<unsigned char>(*iter)] ) {
            results += *iter;
        } else {
            static char const hexChars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            results += '%';
            results += hexChars[(*iter >> 4) & 0x0F];
            results += hexChars[(*iter     ) & 0x0F];
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It's not clear, however, how the original string is encoded. Absent that information you'd have to take the explicit conversion to UTF-8 into account.

Comment: If you want UTF-8, of course, you have to start with UTF-8.  That would be a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

For platform independent feature-rich Unicode handling "de facto" standard library is ICU that is used by many fortune 500 companies and open-source projects...
The license is open-source and friendly for use in commercial development

It could be overkill if you just want to use some simple conversions though...

[http://site.icu-project.org](http://site.icu-project.org/)

If you just need a simple portable utf-8 c++ library you can try [http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/)

hth